# SFML loadFromFile not showing image

Tags: c++, sfml

I've been trying to output an image using SFML in C++ VS 2013, but when I use loadFromFile, it doesn't display anything, I've checked the working directories, it's the project directory, and the image is in a file in it. Here is the code:-

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main(){
sf::VideoMode videomode(800, 800);
sf::RenderWindow window(videomode, "HEllO");
sf::Sprite sprite;
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("Images\aline.png");
sprite.setTexture(texture);
sprite.setPosition(200, 200);
while (window.isOpen()){
    window.clear();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)){
        if ((event.type == sf::Event::Closed))
            window.close();
        }

    }
}
```

The place where my image is:
Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Images

Working directory:-
$(ProjectDir)

If you have any idea why this is happening, please help me. I'm sorry if the question is a stupid/obvious one.

Comment: Why is there a `:` in the path?

Comment: Yes, I removed it just after submitting the question after I realized but the problem persists

Comment: \  is a escape character, use  \\ . Common practice is to check if opening/reading a file succeeded before continuing. `loadFromFile` returns a bool to indicate success or failure.

Comment: Images\aline.png gives me an error in the console "Failed to load image Imagesline.png" and some strange characters, Images\\aline.png displays the same blank black window with nothing to show :/

Comment: I experienced similar rendering problems in SFML. I realized that it was caused by my very old integrated GPU or its drivers that could have some sort of bug. Check if you can draw a simple primitive.

Comment: Is it showing the error after correcting the file path to '"Images\\aline.png"'? Is the `loadFromFile()` function returning true or false? Are you running the program directly through the explorer or using an IDE "Run" button?

Comment: @Luna Does the second give some error? If it gives the same, then try putting image in the same directory, or try using "/".

Comment: It (Images\\aline.png) doesn't give an error, but doesn't display anything but a black window, I also tried using '/', and it also displays the same black window only, I'm running it directly through the explorer

Comment: What's your GPU? Have you tried to draw a primitive?

Comment: I'll compile your code and check the program, but not now. Looks like you won't be able to use SFML on your current machine due to old graphics card/drivers. Could you tell me what's the model of your graphics card? You can determine it by using programs like GPU-Z.

Comment: Just confirmed my theory: I've checked your program on my newer PC and it works as it should. However on my old notebook it does not. As I mentioned, the problem is caused by your graphics card or its drivers. You can try to update these drivers. If it doesn't help, you will have to change your development workstation or consider upgrading your computer (which probably won't be possible).

Comment: @Luna Could you tell me what version of sfml do you have?

Comment: The graphics card is Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600. The problem isn't with my graphics card though, the laptop is only a year old, and the images are loaded successfully when I try loading them using allegro, I'm considering just switching to it, but I don't know. Lasoloz my SFML version is 2.3.2.

Comment: I have an Intel graphics card too, but it's about eight years old. I think SFML should work on your card. Try to update the GPU drivers. [Click here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html?iid=dc_iduu) - this software should help you to find suitable drivers

Comment: I checked the GPU drivers and they're up-to-date, still not working, can getting an older SFML version help?

Comment: You can give it a try.

Comment: Tried SFML 2.0, still not working, I guess I'll just switch to allegro then, thanks for trying to help though <3 :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is ok. but make sure you don't mix Debug/Release libs. if you mixed them your pic won't be shown on screen. from comments the weird characters in console output means you indeed linked release libs with debug mode or vise-versa.

Comment: Oh, Wow! Thank you so so much! I didn't even think of that, I thought I could link all the libs and it would just use the correct libs lol ;D

Comment: lol, we all wish the compiler will do it for us, but unfortunately we have to link them individually

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious things to change would be:

1. Check the return value from `loadFromFile()` - it actually tells you if it thinks it succeeded.
2. Your code `texture.loadFromFile("Images\aline.png");` should be `texture.loadFromFile("Images/aline.png");`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
texture.loadFromFile("Images\aline.png");
```

to

```
texture.loadFromFile("Images/aline.png");
                    //      ^
```

Or if on Windows, `\\` should work as well.

```
texture.loadFromFile("Images\\aline.png");
```