# SFML image not showing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I came across similar issue however it didn't help me so far: [SFML loadFromFile not showing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315448/sfml-loadfromfile-not-showing-image)

the issue:

Using debug build. The the program goes full screen however nothing is showing. The cursor also goes into a blue spinning state as if something is getting processed.

what I tried:

to make sure the debug libs and the release libs are not conflicting.

moving all the *-d-2.dll into a separate folder, and using system PATH variable to reference them.

moving all the *-d.lib and *-d.pdb into a separate folder and setting the linker to reference only that folder for libraries.

setting the additional dependencies to these only:

sfml-graphics-d.lib, sfml-window-d.lib,sfml-system-d.lib, sfml-network-d.lib, sfml-audio-d.lib

I tried adding ways to check for errors in code but have not gotten any errors.

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;

using sf::VideoMode;
using sf::RenderWindow;
using sf::Style::Fullscreen;
using sf::Keyboard;
using sf::Texture;
using sf::Sprite;
using sf::Shape;

int main()
{
    // create video mode object
    VideoMode *vm = new VideoMode(1920, 1080);
    if (vm == NULL) { cerr << "Video mode null\n"; exit(1); }
    // create window
    RenderWindow *window = new RenderWindow(*vm, "Timber!", Fullscreen);
    if (window == NULL) { cerr << "widnow is null\n"; exit(1); }

    // set up background
    // texture object
    Texture textureBackground;
    // load texture onto object
    if (!textureBackground.loadFromFile("../Graphics/background.png"))
    { cerr << "file loading failed!\n"; exit(1); }

    // create sprite object
    Sprite *spriteBackground = new Sprite();
    if (window == NULL) { cerr << "spriteBackground is null\n"; exit(1); }
    // set sprite to the background texture
    spriteBackground->setTexture(textureBackground);
    // set sprite position
    spriteBackground->setPosition(0, 0);

    // main game loop
    while (window->isOpen())
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window->close();
        }

        window->draw(*spriteBackground);

        // clear everything from last frame
        window->clear();

        // show what we drew
        window->display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the path correct?  Try to use an absolute path.

Comment: The reason your cursor is in "a blue spinning state as if something is getting processed" is because you are not handling events. The operating system is sending events to your program and when they don't get processed, the operating system presumes that your program has frozen, hence the cursor. Also, your "sprite test" is actually testing the window.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SFML. But when I tested your code, I got a black screen. The code in `while (window->isOpen()){}` might be the problem. Because I am able to load the image after replacing  the `while(){}` in the link you posted.  Have you tried the code in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315448/sfml-loadfromfile-not-showing-image)?

PS: I put all the required lib and dll aside the exe.

Used LIB:

```
sfml-window-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-graphics-d.lib
```

Comment: @Andy An Hi,  is your problem solved? If the answer was helpful, you could click '✔' to mark reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this commit, I'm sure find something helpful
https://github.com/anuraghit/timber-man/commit/d95418436894d7d22711dec175ec287efc00bfff#diff-c740d06c2060b02a56a855e4e4d29d1eae6454ec1ebb89d2029421b6de0e5594
also make sure your config is in x86

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).